# JavaFX application deployment on MAC OSX (10.10) compatible with modern intel CPU architecture

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, javafx, powerpc

I want to deploy javafx application for use on MAC OSX. The code compiles successfully on MAC OSX and generates .dmg and .pkg installer, but when I execute and run the code it shows this error "powerPC applications are no longer supported". I know apple switched from powerPC architecture to Intel CPU architecture. I just want to know how can I deploy mac applications using eclipse so that they will run perfectly on latest mac systems.

Comment: Where are you compiling? Where do you try to run? (Mac OS Version, Hardware)

Comment: Also define "latest", powerPC was given up quite a while ago (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple%27s_transition_to_Intel_processors)

Comment: Tell us exactly how you did the build